# C++ Code works in 32 bit but fails in 64 bit with heap corruption

Tags: visual-c++

I am new to C++ and need help in resolving the heap corruption issue on 64 bit. Below is the code that works on 32 bit but not on 64 bit.

```
#define a 3
#define b 4


char *c[b-a+1];

//some allocation code to char *c[b-a+1]

//destructor code that fails

for (x = a; x <= b; x++) {

  if c([x-a]){

    char * y =(char*)c[x-a];

    free(y);

    c[x-a]=null;

}

}
```

Please note this is not my code, just something i inherited and need to fix.

Any help is appreciated.

Thanks,

Comment: Please format code so it can be read - ie please read your question after saving and see it makes sense

Comment: I don't see where `null` is defined.  If that's wrong, I could see it corrupting the heap (freeing something that was never malloc-ed, or freeing the same value twice).

Comment: The code looks OK. My guess is that either you are freeing the same pointer twice (elsewhere) _or_ not all pointers in the array point to memory allocated with free (e.g., they are uninitialized and hold some garbage).

Comment: I suspect you'll need to show more of the code before people can help.  How are the contents of the c array allocated for example.

Comment: Seconding what Frank Boyne said. But also post actual code  - what you posted has syntax errors so it's clearly not really what's in the problem code.  And for problems such as memory corruption it's often very small details that matter.

Comment: Thank you all for quick replies.
I will try my best to provide as much as I can without disclosing any information which I shouldnt be.

Comment: The location where you notice corruption is very rarely the location where the corruption occurred.

Answer (score 0):

in your code **b-a+1 = 2**

so ..

**x = a**  it means **x = 3**

**so  ... x <= b**   means while **<= 4**,  but array size is **2**.  it's a **runtime err**

and also is there any declaration of variable x ?

**if c([x a]) { ... }** is it correct syntax ?
maybe you want to say
**if (c[x-a]) { ... }**